# How can move my blog content properly aligned

Tags: html, css, blogs

As you can see below screenshot, my page content is too much aligned towards left, I want to move to 10 or 20px right.

When I use padding-left :10px, then the .content moves right and overlaps with the sidebar.

Blog url - [qavalidation.com](https://qavalidation.com)

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code of html and css?

Comment: use overall padding to the body. If this is not what you're actually looking for, please add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set padding for `.entry` instead of `.content`

```
.entry {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `padding-left` to `.entry h4` or more padding to that element.

```
.post-title, .entry h4 {
font-weight: bold;
color: #568e90;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[image]

More padding to align with the `bullet lists`

[image]